# --dry-run Execute the migration as a dry run

Tags: doctrine-orm

Can anyone tell the meaning of **"dry run"** in Doctrine 2? I am not able to find it on Google.

I can only get some information by using this command

> php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --help

which outputs

> --dry-run           Execute the migration as a dry run.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dry run in the context of an console command means to run all actions for gathering informations, you get all verbose output, which will be executed, but nothing is really executed. So you can see, what the command will do, but can be safe, your database won't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

If you are try latest version of symfony3

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

you can find exact changes are deployed in database -

if you okay with changes run following command in console -

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: Be careful, schema update and migration aren't the same thing... :)